# Pine Script "Higher High and Lower Low Breakout/Breakdown"

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Seeking assistance in creating a Pine Script indicator for a 1-hour Heikin Ashi chart. The strategy involves identifying higher highs in green candles, adding a buffer of 30, and Label as "Breakout" if the green candles break above this adjusted level. Similarly, for "Breakdown" signals, the script should detect lower lows in red candles, subtract a buffer of 30, and label "Breakdown" if the red candles break below this adjusted level.

I am new for writing codes but have built this in my minimal knowledge. Currently this is showing the breakout and breakdown higher high and lower low respectively but what I need is higher high + 30 find the next green candles if this crossover then it should highlight as Breakout.
Breakdown = Lower low -30 if red candle break this then highlight breakdown.

I tried crossover but I was not able to achieve. Please assist me in building this indicator.
I want to learn more on scripting.

```
//@version=5
indicator("InProgress", overlay = true)
Buffer = input(30, title="Buffer")
plot(high + Buffer,'HH+B',color.new(color.green, 75),linewidth=3,style=plot.style_stepline)
plot(low - Buffer,'LL-B',color.new(color.red, 75),linewidth=3,style=plot.style_stepline)

higherHigh = high > high[1]
lowerLow = low < low[1]

IsGreen = close > open
IsRed = open > close
bothGreen = IsGreen and IsGreen[1]
HH1 = bothGreen and higherHigh
bothRed = IsRed and IsRed[1]
LL1 = bothRed and lowerLow

HH2 = HH1 ? high[1] + Buffer : na
buy_condition = close > HH2

LL2 = LL1 ? low[1] - Buffer : na
sell_condition = close < LL2

last_signal = 0
Buy_final = buy_condition and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == -1)
Sell_final = sell_condition and (nz(last_signal[1]) == 0 or nz(last_signal[1]) == 1)
last_signal := Buy_final ? 1 : Sell_final ? -1 : last_signal[1]

plotshape(Buy_final, title='Buy Label', text='Breakout', location=location.belowbar, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
plotshape(Sell_final, title='Sell Label', text='Breakdown', location=location.abovebar , style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))


//To highlight background before Breakout / Breakdown this acts as caution
LS = 0
HH1B = HH1 and (nz(LS[1]) == 0 or nz(LS[1]) == -1)
LL1B = LL1 and (nz(LS[1]) == 0 or nz(LS[1]) == 1)
LS := HH1B ? 1 : LL1B ? -1 : LS[1]
bgcolor(HH1B or LL1B ? color.new(color.green, 75) : na, title='HH & LL Background')
```